# Intersection of two paraboloids (count the points)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Consider two paraboloids with equations

$z = a(x - x_1) ^2 + a(y - y_1) ^2 + z_1$

$z = b(x - x_2) ^2 + b(y - y_2) ^2 + z_2$

Assume the coefficients are given.

How may I try to count the number of their intersection points? (0, 1, inf)

I tried geometric approach but failed to solve one case with paraboloids facing opposite directions.

I don't want to use numerical approaches. But maybe numpy could help with some exact solution?

In the analytical approach I progressed until treating the equation $a(x - x_1) ^2 + a(y - y_1) ^2 + z_1 = b(x - x_2) ^2 + b(y - y_2) ^2 + z_2$
as quadratic equation of $x$. Now I can compute Discriminant of a Discriminant... but what can I explore next?

Comment: This might help. [Matrix representation of conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections)

Answer (score 1):

Calling $A = \left(\matrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&0}\right),\ \  B_1=\left(0,0,-\frac 1a\right),\ \ B_2=\left(0,0,-\frac 1b\right),\ \ p=(x,y,z)',\ \ p_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i)',\ \ i = 1,2$ we have

$$
\mathcal{P}_1\to (p-p_1)'A(p-p_1)+B_1(p-p_1)=0\\
\mathcal{P}_2\to (p-p_2)'A(p-p_2)+B_2(p-p_2)=0\\
$$

now if $p\in\mathcal{P}_1\cap\mathcal{P}_2$ then

$$
\mathcal{P}_1-\mathcal{P}_2 = 2(x_2-x_1)x+2(y_2-y_1)y+\left(\frac 1b-\frac 1a\right)z+x_1^2-x_2^2+y_1^2-y_2^2+\frac{z_1}{a}-\frac{z_2}{b}=0
$$

is the plane containing the intersection conic.

NOTE

This intersection exists as long as the conic resulting from the elimination of $z$ between $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ is real.

Eliminating $z$ in $(1)$ we got

$$
\left(\matrix{x\\ y}\right)\left(\matrix{a-b&2(bx_2-ax_1)\\ 2(by_2-ay_1)& a-b}\right)\left(\matrix{x & y}\right)+a(x_1^2+y_1^2)-b(x_2^2+y_2^2)+z_1-z_2=0
$$

Follows a plot showing the case

$$
a=3,b=-1,x_1=\frac 12y_1=\frac 13,x_2=\frac 13,y_2=\frac 45,z_1=0,z_3=3
$$

[image]